# How to document parameters in Django REST Swagger 2?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-swagger

I used to specify the parameters using YAML Docstring, but they have now been deprecated. I have tried using `coreapi.Field`, as follows:

```
coreapi.Field(
    name='id',
    type='integer',
    required=True,
    location='query'
)
```

but it only works with`ViewSet.list`, and not with, say, `ViewSet.create`. According to [this report](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/549), this has been an on-going issue. The solution provided in the comments are quite hackish to me. I hope someone has already found (or came up with) a neater solution or alternative, perhaps a plugin or something.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is so late, but just for some help, you have to override the Schema generator to customize it, this doc explains django rest swagger 2 integration step by step:
[Django Rest Swagger 2 comprehensive documentation](https://github.com/m-haziq/django-rest-swagger-docs)

you may think it a bit hacky but works perfectly fine.

EDIT: This documentation can be followed for function based views but if you already have class based views, you can directly use this package: https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of it all wrong, but isn't those steps too much? I've created my models, I've created my serializers, I've created my views, why do I then have to move heaven and earth just to show the fields? Why can't the swagger automatically follow through and pick up these fields?

Comment: That document is for function based views, if you have already written class based then you should directly use this updated package: https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html